# Jenkins parameter list drop down based on user selection

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Is there a plugin/ groovy script I can use for the following?

I have a list of clients on which i need to start tests
I have access to test list/hardware list for each client in my master(In a flat file)

When i select a client using parameterized build, I need to update the contents of the file relevant to the client selected

I tried looking around but could not find a solution to my problem. Would appreciate your help.

Also, is there a way i can convert that choice which is a string into a number, key value map?

Example:
Master Server has the below directory structure:

```
Client1
|_HW_list.log
   HW_1
   HW_2
|_TestLst.log
  test1
  test2
Client2
|_HW_list.log
   HW_1
|_TestLst.log
  testA
  testB
```

When i try to start a job and i choose Client1 from the parameterized plugin, I should be able to list HW_1 and HW_2 under devices, and list test1,test2 in the test list.

After i choose the tests, i should be able to pass this information to the slave node.

Comment: not clear what you want to do.. do you need to generate a new file for one client ? if so, could you provide file examples.

Comment: I just added a example, please let me know if that helps. Ill try to elaborate further if its still confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You need “Active Choice Reactive Parameter” plugin for Jenkins https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin . You will need to have 3 build parameters in your configuration:

1. "Active Choices parameter" - let's name it "CLIENT". Use it as a "single select" type with a groovy script for it in the respective field like this:

   `return ["Client1", "Client2", "Client3"]`
2. And a build parameter "Active Choices Reactive" as a pair to the previous one - let's name it "TESTS". use it as a "single select" type with a groovy script for it in the respective field like this:

   ```
   switch(CLIENT){
    case "Client1":
   return ["Tests1", "Tests11", "Tests111"]
    break
   case "Client2":
       return ["Tests2", "Tests22", "Tests222", "Tests2222"]
   break
    case "Client3":
       return ["Tests3", "Tests33", "Tests333"]
    break
   }
   ```

If you do not need to have a dependency between HW devices and tests, just

3. And a build parameter "Active Choices Reactive" as a pair to the previous one - let's name it "HW". use it as a "single select" type with a groovy script for it in the respective field like this:

   ```
   switch(CLIENT){
    case "Client1":
   return ["HW1", "HW2"]
    break
   case "Client2":
       return ["HW1"]
   break
    case "Client3":
       return ["HW2"]
    break
   }
   ```

Another option would be to set a "Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter" and configure usage of HW and TESTS.